# Receive error when i try to update data in my fireStore collection

Tags: angular, firebase, google-cloud-functions, angular7

I'm starting to code my new website and search to update "users" collection on fireStore database

I'm using Angular 7 and Cloud Firestore.

I have created my first collection "users" who contain my informations for my members

My collection screen.

[image: collection screen]

into my crud, you can see my update user data fonction

```
  // Update User
  UpdateUser(user: User){
    this.userRef.update({
      firstName: user.firstName,
      lastName: user.lastName,
      displayName: user.displayName,
      photoURL: user.photoURL,
      emailVerified: user.emailVerified,
      birthday: user.birthday,
      addressOne: user.addressOne,
      addressTwo: user.addressTwo,
      zipCode: user.zipCode,
      city: user.city,
      country: user.country,
      phoneOne: user.phoneOne,
      phoneTwo: user.phoneTwo,
      profilType: user.profilType,
      profilPicture: user.profilPicture,
      admin: user.admin,
      moderator: user.admin
    })
  }
```

and you will see my form update fonction here

```
  updateUserData(){
    this.edituserprofileForm = this.fb.group({
      firstName: ['', [Validators, Validators.minLength(2)]],
      lastName: ['', [Validators, Validators.minLength(2)]],
      address: [],
      address2: [],
      city: [],
      country: [],
      zipCode: ['', [Validators.pattern('^[0-9]+$')]],
      phoneOne: ['', [Validators.pattern('^[0-9]+$')]]
    })
  }

  goBack(){
    this.location.back();
  }

  UserUpdateForm(){
    this.crudApi.UpdateUser(this.edituserprofileForm.value) // Update user data using  CRUD API
    console.log(this.edituserprofileForm.value);
  }
```

At the moment, when i submit my form i receive this error

> Reference.update failed: First argument contains undefined in property 'edit.eSwVu5bujlYkSH8gZiIlW0LHz5i2.displayName'
>       at validateFirebaseData"

and i don't understand why i receive this error

Thanks by advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your form does just have address data but in your update function you also update `displayName`, `photoURL`, etc. which are undefined in the user object the function receives from your user form.

You should remove the missing data field or create a new function to update the form data.

```
UpdateUser(user: User){
  this.userRef.update({
    firstName: user.firstName,
    lastName: user.lastName,
    addressOne: user.addressOne,
    addressTwo: user.addressTwo,
    zipCode: user.zipCode,
    city: user.city,
    country: user.country,
    phoneOne: user.phoneOne
  })
}
```